Google Apps Script Error: 'Script function onSubmitOpening could not be found' Despite Correct Setup
I am working on a little project for a restaurant, where I am using ChatGPT to write code for an opening and closing a task list on Google Apps Script. I have a submit button on the sheet triggers notification, my code on the "employer" side is as follows. The code works fine on the "employer side", where I can get notifications, etc., but when I use a dummy account to be an "employee", it states:

"Script function onSubmitOpening could not be found

What's wrong with the code?

function onSubmitOpening() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Opening");

  // Define the range for the "CHECK" and "INITIALS" columns
  var checkColIndex = 3; // Index for the "CHECK" column (assuming it's the 5th column)
  var initialsColIndex = 4; // Index for the "INITIALS" column (assuming it's the 6th column)
  var itemColIndex = 1; // Index for the "ITEM" column (assuming it's the 2nd column)

  // Find the cell next to "Submitted by:"
  var submittedByRange = sheet.createTextFinder("Submitted by:").findNext();
  if (!submittedByRange) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Could not find the 'Submitted by:' cell.");
    return;
  }
  var submittedByName = sheet.getRange(submittedByRange.getRow(), submittedByRange.getColumn() + 1).getValue().toString().trim();

  // Check completion and notify
  checkCompletionAndNotify(sheet, itemColIndex, checkColIndex, initialsColIndex, "Opening Checklist", submittedByName);

  // Protect the sheet, allowing only "CHECK" and "INITIALS" columns to be edited
  protectSheet(sheet, checkColIndex, initialsColIndex);
}

function checkCompletionAndNotify(sheet, itemColIndex, checkColIndex, initialsColIndex, sheetName, submittedByName) {
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var incompleteTasks = [];
  var allTasksCompleted = true;

  // Ensure that all "CHECK" and "INITIALS" columns are filled only for rows where ITEM exists
  for (var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) { // Start from row 3 (index 2)
    var itemValue = (data[i][itemColIndex] || "").toString().trim();
    var checkValue = (data[i][checkColIndex] || "").toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    var initialsValue = (data[i][initialsColIndex] || "").toString().trim();

    // Skip rows where ITEM is empty
    if (itemValue === "") {
      Logger.log("Row " + (i + 1) + " skipped because ITEM is empty.");
      continue;
    }

    // Log the values being checked
    Logger.log("Row " + (i + 1) + " - ITEM: " + itemValue + ", CHECK: " + checkValue + ", INITIALS: " + initialsValue);

    if (checkValue === "" || initialsValue === "") {
      allTasksCompleted = false;
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Please complete all required fields then submit.");
      return;
    }

    if (checkValue !== "yes") {
      incompleteTasks.push(itemValue); // Use itemValue directly for logging incomplete tasks
      allTasksCompleted = false;
    }
  }

  // Send an email notification and generate a PDF based on the completion status
  var emailAddress = "leekaiyunjenny@gmail.com";
  var now = new Date();
  var year = now.getFullYear();
  var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = now.getDate();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  var minute = now.getMinutes();

  var emailSubject = sheetName + " Submission Notification";
  var emailBody;

  if (allTasksCompleted) {
    emailBody = "All the items have been successfully submitted at " + year + "/" + month + "/" + day + " at " + hour + ":" + minute + " by " + submittedByName;
  } else {
    // Format incomplete tasks as a list, each item on a new line
    var itemList = incompleteTasks.map(function(task) {
      return task;
    }).join("\n");

    emailBody = "Good day! Kindly find attached the " + sheetName + " report, submitted at " + year + "/" + month + "/" + day + " at " + hour + ":" + minute + ". The following items in the " + sheetName + " still need to be completed by " + submittedByName + ":\n" + itemList;
  }

  // Generate the PDF
  var pdfBlob = createPDF(sheet);

  // Send the email with the attached PDF
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: emailAddress,
    subject: emailSubject,
    body: emailBody,
    attachments: [pdfBlob]
  });

  // Clear the "CHECK" and "INITIALS" columns after submission, leaving the headings intact
  clearColumns(sheet, checkColIndex, initialsColIndex);
}

function createPDF(sheet) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheet.getId() + "/export?format=pdf&size=A4&portrait=true&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=true&fzr=false&gid=" + sheetId;

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });

  return response.getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf");
}

function clearColumns(sheet, checkColIndex, initialsColIndex) {
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(3, checkColIndex + 1, lastRow - 2, 2).clearContent(); // Clears "CHECK" and "INITIALS" columns from row 3 downwards
}

function protectSheet(sheet, checkColIndex, initialsColIndex) {
  // Protect the entire sheet
  var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Protect sheet except CHECK and INITIALS columns');

  // Unprotect the "CHECK" and "INITIALS" columns
  var unprotectedRange = sheet.getRange(3, checkColIndex + 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 2, 2);
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges([unprotectedRange]);

  // Set the owner of the sheet
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}`

I followed ChatGPT's instruction to set up a trigger but it doesn't seem to work.



It looks that you uploaded the same image twice

Also, you should try reproducing using the minimal code and adding it to the question instead of adding the whole code. Ref. [mcve]. P.D. The on-form submit trigger only works when there is a Google Form linked to the spreadsheet, but you have not mentioned that there is one.

This is a partial answer because the question needs more details.
As you are using a sheet as a form instead of using a Google Form, the installable trigger set as on form submit will not be triggered. Considering this, to reduce code smells it's better to remove this trigger.
As the prompt for ChatCGPT was not included we can't blame this tool for given the instructions to add this trigger.
